# Can not get custom ASP.NET MVC RangeAttribute to work on DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, model, custom-attributes

I'm trying to put a date constraint on a DateTime field. When I use hardcoded values it works out of the box.

But when I create my own RangeAttribute class, it doesn't.

### This works

*ViewModel:*

```
public class OrderViewModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Ship Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [Range(typeof(DateTime), "4/3/2013", "3/4/2014",
            ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}")]
        public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
}
```

*HTML Output:*

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Ship Date must be a date." data-val-range="Value for Ship Date must be between 3/4/2013 12:00:00 AM and 3/4/2014 12:00:00 AM" data-val-range-max="03/04/2014 00:00:00" data-val-range-min="03/04/2013 00:00:00" data-val-required="The Ship Date field is required." id="ShipDate" name="ShipDate" type="date" value="01/01/0001">
```

---

### This doesn't work

*Custom attribute*

```
public class ShipDateAttribute : RangeAttribute
    {
        public ShipDateAttribute()
            : base(typeof(DateTime), DateTime.Now.AddDays(+1).ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.AddYears(+1).ToShortDateString()) { }
    }
```

*ViewModel*

```
public class OrderViewModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Ship Date")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        [ShipDate(ErrorMessage = "...")]
        public DateTime ShipDate { get; set; }
}
```

*HTML Output*

```
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-date="The field Ship Date must be a date." data-val-required="The Ship Date field is required." id="ShipDate" name="ShipDate" type="date" value="01/01/0001">
```